# Cannot access e.target.id even though its there when i log e.target in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getClubs } from '../../actions/club';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ViewPlayers = ({ clubs, loading, getClubs }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getClubs();
  }, [getClubs]);

  const [form, editForm] = useState({
    club_id: ''
  });

  const selClub = e => {
    console.log(e.target); --> Has the id value set to the correct id
    console.log(e.target.id); --> outputs empty string
  };
  const submitData = e => {};
  return loading === true ? (
    <div>
      <h1>wait</h1>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className='container'>
      <h3>View players</h3>
      <form onSubmit={e => submitData(e)}>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <label className='mt-3'>
            <strong>Select Club</strong>
          </label>
          <select
            className='form-control mb-3'
            name='club'
            value={form.club_id}
            onChange={e => selClub(e)}
          >
            {clubs.map(data => {
              return (
                <option key={data._id} id={data._id}>
                  {data.name}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ViewPlayers.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  clubs: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  getClubs: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  clubs: state.club.data,
  loading: state.club.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getClubs })(ViewPlayers);
```

Okay so i have set the id on option tag of the select statement to the id of the current club..
When i console.log(e.target) i can see the id value set for all the clubs in my data set.. But if i console.log(e.target.id) i get 'empty string' even though it is set on` the above console.log to the correct id???? if i do e.target.value i get the correct value also???

How is it not seeing the e,target.id???

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you tried `onClick` of the option element to get the id? As I know select element doesn't get the id of its options. In addition, you can get the id of option element which has `selected` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would even need to use the `id` attribute on `option` tags. You can specify an `id` for your `select` tag, at least it makes sense. For `option` tags what you want to do is specify their `value` attributes. Then you can access a selected value using `e.target.value` in your `onChange` handler.

```
<select
  className='form-control mb-3'
  name='club'
  value={form.club_id}
  onChange={e => selClub(e)}
>
  {clubs.map(data => {
    return (
      <option key={data._id} value={data._id}>
        {data.name}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>
```